# forEach results in $0 is immutable error

Tags: arrays, swift, foreach

```
protocols.forEach { $0.prop = nil }
```

results in:

```
Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable
```

I worked around this with:

```
protocols.forEach
{
    var protocol = $0

    protocol.prop = nil
}
```

But why is the compiler okay with this?  I would expect it could figure this out.

Comment: Are objects structs or the instance of a class?

Comment: @vacawama No, thanks for asking, they are `protocol`s actually.

Comment: Add `": class"` to your protocol if everything that implements your protocol is a class, and it will work.

Comment: @vacawama The protocol comes from a framework developed/maintained by other, so I don't want to just a `: class`.

Comment: That's fine.  At least now you know why you have to do the `var` workaround and understand that it will only do what you want if the items in your array are instances of a `class`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have an array of items that implement a protocol.  If you don't tell Swift that this is an `AnyObject` protocol (or `class` protocol in earlier versions of Swift), it will assume that it can be implemented by a `struct`.

In a `forEach` loop, you will essentially have a `let` variable (called `$0` by default) assigned to each value in the array in turn.  If you have an array of objects (instances of a `class`), then you can modify properties of that item.  If you have an array of `struct` items, then those will be immutable.  If you have an array of items that implement a protocol, then Swift will treat them as the more restrictive `struct` unless you add `: AnyObject` (or `: class` in earlier versions of Swift) to your protocol definition.

For example:

```
protocol Xyzzy: AnyObject {
    var prop: Int? { get set }
}

class Fred: Xyzzy, CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { String(describing: prop) }
    var prop: Int? = 17
}

let objects: [Xyzzy] = [Fred(), Fred(), Fred()]

print(objects)  //  [Optional(17), Optional(17), Optional(17)]

objects.forEach { $0.prop = nil }

print(objects)  // [nil, nil, nil]
```

Your workaround:

```
protocols.forEach
{
    var protocol = $0

    protocol.prop = nil
}
```

works for `class` objects because it creates a new `var` pointer to the object, and then that allows you to modify the object.  Note, this workaround only works for instances of classes.  If your protocol is implemented by a `struct`, then the new `var` will be a new copy of the `struct` item, and the original ones in the array will not be changed.

Comment: Great answer that helps getting a deeper understanding of Swift. Thank you!

Comment: So why is this? Is there a deeper reason？ Something like that  memory layout / compiler improve / Struct is value type in swift ?

Comment: @0xxxD, In Swift, all types are known at compile time. Protocols that can be adopted by structs and classes are treated as the more restrictive struct because Swift will not make a dynamic decision at runtime. Yes structs are value types. When they’re assigned to a let constant such as a loop variable, all properties are immutable. Declaring a protocol as `class` tells Swift you’ll only use it with classes and the Swift at compile time will treat variables of that protocol type as references.

Comment: As of 2021 (?) the protocol needs `AnyObject` instead of `class`, as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: @adamjansch, thank you for helping me to keep this answer up to date!

Answer (score 28):

How to change `Array` of `Structs`

for every element:

```
itemsArray.indices.forEach { itemsArray[$0].someValue = newValue }
```

for specific element:

```
itemsArray.indices.filter { itemsArray[$0].propertyToCompare == true }
                  .forEach { itemsArray[$0].someValue = newValue }
```

Comment: I almost used this, but I would have had to comment on what was going on to future-self or others.It also didn't feel so swiftly. So found there's `enumerated` as part of sequence protocol. I used that instead.
 `itemsArray.enumerated().map` 
Map will now have two default parameter $0 is the index and $1 the value. or `itemsArray.enumerated().map{ index, value in //morecode }`

Comment: Hats off, you saved my time :)